# What does the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading some data from Excel using Pandas in Python, this is how I read the data:

```
data_frame = pd.read_excel(file_location, usecols=catcode_column)
data_frame2 = pd.read_excel(file_location, usecols=smpl_column)
```

where the file_location is a string of the path and the usecols is simply the column that I want to read from the Excel file. Then I have 2 for loops, the first is is to just use the first 5 characters on the given column and the second uses the entire string:

```
    for i in data_frame:
        data_frame["catcode_column"] = data_frame[catcode_column_name].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:5])
    for j in data_frame2:
        data_frame2["smpl_column"] = data_frame2[smpl_column_name].apply(lambda y: y[:])
```

Now, I convert those data frames into lists using the following:

```
catcode_array = data_frame["catcode_column"].values.tolist()
smpl_array = data_frame2["smpl_column"].values.tolist()
```

and the the output when printing the catcode_array and smpl_array give me is the following:

**Catcode Array: ['34123', '42253', '63334']**

**SMPL Array: ['Apartment-Midrise', 'Apartment-Midrise', 'Apartment-Midrise']**

Now, I have a new array initialized to None with a size of 10000 and a counter initialized to 0. I iterate through the **smpl_array**, which is printed above, and if the index i of **smpl_array** is equal to the **building_type_array** index 0, then I want to store the value of the **catcode_array** at index i in the **apartment_midrise** at **counter1** which at the beginning will be 0 so at the first index of that array and then increment the counter. It is worth nothing that **building_type_array** is an array of strings.

```
apartment_midrise = [None] * 10000

counter1 = 0

for i in smpl_array:
    if smpl_array[i] == building_type_array[0]:
        apartment_midrise[counter1] = catcode_array[i]
        counter1 += 1
```

But, I'm getting the following error in the **if** statement above:

`if smpl_array[i] == building_type_array[0]:`

*TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

I've been trying to fix this without any luck. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: i is not a number, it is the current value in smpl_array. change your loop to this: for i in range(len(smpl_array)):

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and let you know if it worked. I'm new to Python and I still don't fully understand its for loops since they're so different, the sintaxis, to other languages such as Java and C @Gal

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you! @Gal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to loop over a list and get the item and it's index in each iteration, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, smpl in enumerate(smpl_array):
    if smpl == building_type_array[0]:
        apartment_midrise[counter1] = catcode_array[i]
        counter1 += 1
```